# Filtering XML using multiple conditions of xquery

Tags: xml, db2, xquery

Hi I have many XML files which have the structure like:

```
<mydoc>
      <EC>
         <spec>
            <name>A para</name>
            <para>A</para>
            <val>40</val>
         </spec>
         <spec>
            <name>Input Voltage</name>
            <para>Vin</para>
            <val>40</val>
         </spec>
      </EC>
</mydoc>
```

I need to filter out only those XML files which has a spec with para=Vin and val>30

What should be my Xquery like? In DB2 I have this so far?

```
for $x in db2-fn:xmlcolumn('TABLE.XMLCOLUMN')/mydoc
```

So this would iterate over all XML files and I will have mydoc element tag in $x but now how do I implement the multiple conditions and return just the name of the spec which satisfies my conditions?

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/db2-native-xml/ and
, http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/sqlxml-vs-xquery/ might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to express this. XPath predicates:

```
for $x in db2-fn:xmlcolumn('TABLE.XMLCOLUMN')/mydoc[EC/spec[para = 'Vin' and val > 40]]
```

Or XQuery's `where` clause. This also uses XPath predicates and I think it is slightly easier to read:

```
for $x in db2-fn:xmlcolumn('TABLE.XMLCOLUMN')/mydoc
let $specs := $x/EC/spec
where ($spec[para = 'Vin' and val > 40])
```

Both should give you the same results.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So this for would iterate over all documents and for each document it iterates over all specs? But I just need 1 return for each document i.e. only if the document satisfies the conditions. How do I do that?

Comment: @Milind So you want to return a single <mydoc> if any of its <spec> descendants meet your criteria? Or only if all of the <spec>s meet the criteria?

Comment: I want to return a single mydoc if any of its spec descendants meet my criteria. Thanks.

Comment: @Milind Updated my answer with new logic that should answer your question.